# Can I use Mini2440 tutorial for Tiny6410?

Tags: microcontroller

Recently I bought Tiny6410, my question is,
Can I use [this link](http://www.thaieasyelec.com/Free-Service-from-ThaiEasyElec/ARM9-mini2440--micro2440-FriendlyARM-Tutorial.html) for Tiny6410 ?

Any experiences ?

---

[Mini2440 is an ARM9 development board, for the Samsung S3C2440 processor](http://www.arm9.net)

Comment: What's a Tiny6410? Question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be some commonality but many differences.
 Read the manual see - the areas that are not relevant will soon be obvious.

[There is an excellent comparison table of all FriendlyARM boards here](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/comparison).

[Mini2440 intro page](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440)

[image]

- Dimension: 100 x 100 mm
  CPU: 400 MHz Samsung S3C2440A ARM920T (max freq. 533 MHz)
  RAM: 64 MB SDRAM, 32 bit Bus
  Flash: 64 MB / 128 MB / 256 MB / 1GB NAND Flash and 2 MB NOR Flash with BIOS
  EEPROM: 256 Byte (I2C)
  Ext. Memory: SD-Card socket
  Serial Ports: 1x DB9 connector (RS232), total: 3x serial port connectors
  USB: 1x USB-A Host 1.1, 1x USB-B Device 1.1
  Audio Output: 3.5 mm stereo jack
  Audio Input: Connector + Condenser microphone
  Ethernet: RJ-45 10/100M (DM9000)
  RTC: Real Time Clock with battery (CR1220)
  Beeper: PWM buzzer
  Camera: 20 pin (2.0 mm) Camera interface
  LCD Interface: 41 pin (1.0 mm) connector for FriendlyARM Displays and VGA Board
  Touch Panel: 4 wire resistive
  User Inputs: 6x push buttons and 1x A/D pot
  User Outputs: 4x LEDs
  Expansion: 40 pin System Bus, 34 pin GPIO, 10 pin Buttons (2.0 mm)
  Debug: 10 pin JTAG (2.0 mm)
  Power: regulated 5V (DC-Plug: 1.35mm inner x 3.5mm outer diameter)
  Power Consumption: Mini2440: 0.3 A, Mini2440 + 3.5" LCD: 0.6 A, Mini2440 + 7" LCD: 1 A
  OS Support
  Windows CE 5 and 6
  Linux 2.6
  Android

[Tiny6410 intro](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny6410)

[image]

- Dimension: 64 x 50 mm
  CPU: 533 MHz Samsung S3C6410A ARM1176JZF-S with VFP-Unit and Jazelle (max freq. 667 MHz)
  RAM: 128 MB / 256 MB DDR RAM, 32 bit Bus
  Flash: 256 MB / 1GB NAND Flash
  Serial, SPI, USB, LCD, CMOS Camera Interface
  Analog Input and Output
  User Outputs: 4x LEDs
  Expansion headers (2.0 mm)
  Debug: 10 pin JTAG (2.0 mm)
  OS Support
  Windows CE 6
  Linux 2.6
  Android
  Ubuntu

---

[Many FriendlyARM documents](http://www.friendlyarm.net/downloads)

Compare schematics to see differences (zips)

[Mini6410 schematic](http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=mini6410_schematic.zip)
 [tiny 6410](http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=tiny6410_schematic.zip)
 [Mini 2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=mini2440_schematic.zip)

---

**Mini2440 Development Board**

The Mini2440 is a practical low-cost ARM9 development board, for the Samsung S3C2440 processor and the use of 
professional power stable core CPU chip to chip and reset security permit system stability. Go to http://www.arm9.net, and download the latest update to inform the latest manuals and systems.